# How to know who is disposing my Bitmap object or where it has been disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, bitmap, dispose

My object is passed through some sophisticated pipeline, in some parts of it, I don't have the code, I need to know what is the location when `Dispose` is called on my `Bitmap`!

Comment: Is it even being disposed? You can't know where it is if it's deep down in some 3rd party library.

Comment: I have the pdb's of other libraries, and the are not obfuscated! I need to know the function name at least where dispose is called.

Comment: if you download the .NET source you can set break points in the .NEt source and then simply set one in the bitmap Dispose method and look at the stack trace

Comment: Where to download it, and how to bind it? I need some link to guide me, thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint on `System.Drawing.Image.Dispose` from your breakpoints window. Then the debugger will stop when `Image.Dispose` is called and you can review where it is called from the Call Stack window.

Don't forget to turn OFF Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do anything with the bitmap class such as `inherit` it and then raise an event on dispose so that you can capture the specific point the object is disposed.

You should however know where dispose is called if you use a disposable object properly.

```
using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(""))
{
  //Do some stuff with B
//Dispose is handled on end of using
}
```

Or where you call `Dispose()` itself.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap("");
//Do some stuff with b
b.Dispose();
```

Your better off setting your code up where you know an object is being disposed. Stepping into the `System.Drawing.Image` object will help you identify it, but you can't do anything other than that in the dispose method.

Comment: I know about Dispose thing sure, but I need to know the point where dispose is being called, I am trying @idursun solution, I think it will solve it!

Comment: Yes, I have explained above that those are the two areas where `Dispose` would inevitably be called. Stepping into the method will just enforce that.